# Automated testing differences between browser test runner and CLI?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have an Ember CLI addon project -- [ui-slider-input](https://github.com/lifegadget/ui-slider-input/commit/3fe213b41365f29d9329563ad158080779496a94) -- which has a VERY basic wrapper around a JS slider widget. This is implemented as a component and the out-of-the-box unit tests for whether a component does or does not render is run. Here's the strange part ...

1. There are no errors when running in the browser (`UiSliderComponent: it renders`)
2. When I run the same tests from CLI with `npm test` (could also have used `ember test` ... no difference) it fails with the following stack trace:

```html
 not ok 7 PhantomJS 1.9 - UiSliderInputComponent: it renders
     ---
     actual: >
         null
     message: >
         Died on test #2     at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:418
             at test (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:284)
             at http://localhost:7357/assets/dummy.js:273
             at http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:77
             at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:14: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this._applyPrecision.bind(this)')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not a Ember CLI problem, it’s a PhantomJS problem.

PhantomJS lacks `Function.prototype.bind`, which you can see is being called in the stacktrace. [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522) discusses the problem. The simplest solution would be to add one:

```
Function.prototype.bind = Function.prototype.bind || function (thisp) {
    var fn = this;
    return function () {
        return fn.apply(thisp, arguments);
    };
};
```

See the thread for more details.

Comment: Buck, this worked great for me when I put it into the test script I was having problems for but when using an Ember-CLI setup where is the best place to add this polyfill so that all unit tests can benefit from it?

Comment: You could just make a script in `vendor` and include it in the `Brocfile.js`.

Comment: And I guess wrap it in a conditional for ENV? I'll give it a whirl. Surprised something like this isn't the default for CLI but I guess it's running at 100mph so probably a future consideration.

Comment: Adding it to Ember CLI has [been discussed](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/2634), but it’s contentious.

Comment: Yeah I could see it might be contentious but in terms of developer happiness and reduction of wasted-time (two things CLI is good at) I'd say this fit the receipt. Either way, thanks for your help. :)